# Make a TextBox in mvc or asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have make at text box in asp.net or MVC. Using jQuery I have added a data table of jQuery on it. I make TextBox searchable while entering any text or number search on the behalf of this and on click add a calendar if selected date from the calendar search according to the data.

Here is a screenshot of Searchable textbox :
[image]

Comment: Are you using a server-side datasource for the datatable?

Comment: What is your question?